# NoSuchMethodError while creating spark session

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark. I am just trying to create a spark session in my local but I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.SHUFFLE_SPILL_NUM_ELEMENTS_FORCE_SPILL_THRESHOLD()Lorg/apache/spark/internal/config/ConfigEntry;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.<init>(SQLConf.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.<clinit>(SQLConf.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.<init>(StaticSQLConf.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.<clinit>(StaticSQLConf.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:938)
```

Similar error has been posted over here: [Error while using SparkSession or sqlcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181540/error-while-using-sparksession-or-sqlcontext)

I am using the same version for spark-core and spark-sql. Here is my build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1" % "provided")
libraryDependencies += ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1" % "provided")
```

I am using scala version 2.11.8.
Can someone explain why I am still getting this error and how to correct it?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same **Spark** and **Scala** versions in your project as the ones installed in the cluster you are going to run?

Comment: I am running the code in my local

Comment: Uhm, that doesn't make much sense. Can you create a little public repo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @shady_vaib Even if you have Spark installed locally, you need to make sure that Spark version matches the spark dependencies you are installing (i.e. 2.3.1). Do `spark-shell --version` to see which spark version you have

Comment: Yes, it was some issue with my spark version. My local version in spark was 3.x. Thank you so much for helping folks.

Comment: @shady_vaib Please upvote or accept my answer as best if it helped in any way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you see a NoSuchMethod error with something like `Lorg/…` in the log, it's usually due to Spark version mismatch. Do you have Spark 2.3.1 installed in your system? Make sure that the dependencies match that of your local or cluster’s Spark version.